# The group of polynomial homeomorphism of the plane

Tags: gn.general-topology, lie-groups, topological-groups

Let  $G$  be the  set  of all  homeomorphisms  $f$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$  such that

both $f$  and  $f^{-1}$ are  polynomial  maps.

We equip $G$ with the  compact open topology and  the obvious  group  structure.

> Is  $G$  with the  compact open topology a  topological group? Is  it  an infinite dimensional  Lie  Group?What  can  be  said  about  finite  dimensional  Lie  groups  which  are  contained   in $G$?(Are  there  some  examples  other than (subgroups of )  Affine$(\mathbb{R}^n)$?

Comment: This group has been heavily studied in algebraic geometry. For a nice survey, you can have a look at *Algebraic Automorphisms of Affine Space* by H. Kraft, Progress in Math. 80 (Birkhäuser), p. 81-105.

Comment: @abx  Very  great  comment. Thank you!

Comment: When a group $G$ is given "is $G$ a topological group" makes no sense. One should rather ask whether $G$ admits interesting/natural group topologies.

Comment: @YCor  I think In the  first version of the  question, I  had also  pointed out to compact open topology. May  be  I  did  not  understand your  comment, correctly?

Comment: @YCor What  about if we  replace  the  compact open topology  by  another one: For  example We  identify  $G$ with certain  subspace of   $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$. with the product topology?(The  identification of  the  space  of  polynomials  with the  space  of their  coefficient).

Comment: I'm sorry, you're right.

Comment: But anyway the compact-open topology for $Homeo(\mathbf{R}^2)$ is, if I'm correct, a group topology (coinciding with compact convergence on compact subsets), and hence in restriction to your subgroup is also a group topology.